# How can I get a minimized Internet Explorer 11 window maximized from a web-page?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I have a web page that get "requests" from an external object imported into the page (object that I don't own). When I get a request from this external object and the browser window is minimized, I have to maximize it.
Also, if the window has more than one tab open, I need to maximize the window showing the caller tab.
How can I do that?

I need to support only ie11 so, no other browser compatibility is needed.

(I already looked for it but I found only old responses that don't work)

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, I don't want to be shady. I'll give you more details (detail that I thought was out of scope). The application is a call center web-app that is paired with a proprietary phone-answering "self-standing" app. So, what I need is to maximize the window if there is an incoming call and the operator is doing something else in another tab of ie or another application. Nothing bad. This is also the reason I only need it for ie11. The problem is that I can do that, but only if there is only one tab opened...thank you Microsoft!

Comment: How does the phone answering app get to launch the web-app

Comment: The web-app import an object that allows the communication between the phone-answering app and the web-app. In the javascript code I receive the call. I can't modify the phone-answering app. These information are really out of of the scope of the question anyway.

Comment: you should look at writing a browser extension

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. The security model prevents a website to change the browser state. Browser state as in changing the window size or bringing it to the foreground.

You could go to the dark sites of the internet and pay some money for an exploit, but you need quite some knowledge and understanding to build a working solution even with the exploit. And as soon as the exploit is public it will be fixed and your solution is worthless.

Comment: It thougth the same at first but, that's not true. In ie11 try this:  window.focus();  
window.moveTo(window.screenLeft,  window.screenTop);  window.resizeTo(window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight);

Answer (score 0):

The `alert` function brings attention to the tab initiating it. It maximize the browser if minimized, and switch the tabs to the one that has the alert:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>

          //This line gives you 2000 millisecond to minimize the tab or open another tab
          //Then after the time elapsed, the alert will maximize the tab and show it 
          myVar = setTimeout(maximizeTab, 2000);

          function maximizeTab()
          {
               alert('hello world');
          }
      </script>
     </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, i saw this possibilities, but unfortunately this is not the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is permitted you can write a webservice e.g. with Go (140 LOC) and start it on the client machine. Then request comming from the web page have to be matched to the system calls of the running OS. I do not see another solution.